# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread, during an http call

Tags: java, out-of-memory

Sometimes I'm getting a runtime the error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnectionPool.put(RealConnectionPool.kt:101)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:258)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
    at com.ids.decoretorPatternHttpCall.MTConnect.httpCall(MTConnect.java:39)
    at com.ids.factoryPatternProtocol.CallFactory.checkProtocol(CallFactory.java:100)
    at com.ids.factoryPatternProtocol.CallFactory.listDevices(CallFactory.java:46)
    at com.ids.main.IdsMain.main(IdsMain.java:94)
```

After lots of checks, I would have understood what's happening. When the device switched off, the application recieve a connection time out and this event throw the error above. I've read some online topics about this  problem and it should be the loop code. But now the application has been working for 2h and it's running well.

Method with loop that calls httpcall(). The MTConnect's Constructor receives  the server name(ip) and the port.
mt.httpCall() return a buffer of byte[], otherwise catch an exception(IOException). But in this case I get OutOfMemoryError.

```
@Override
protected void checkProtocol(List<DeviceMTConnect> devicesFactory, int line, DeviceDAO devDAO, Logger logger, ConsoleHandler ch, long minute) {
    DeviceMTConnect device = null;
    long time = 0;
    int i = 0;


    if (minute > 0) {
        time = minute * 60 * 1000L;
    }


    for (DeviceMTConnect d : devicesFactory) {
        d.setLinea(linea);
        d.setDeviceState(1);
        //  System.out.println(d);


    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            while (i < devicesFactory.size()) {

                devicesFactory.get(i).setStatoDevice(devDAO.getDeviceStatus(devicesFactory.get(i).getDeviceCode(), logger, ch));

                if (devicesFactory.get(i).getDeviceState() > 0) {
                    if (devicesFactory.get(i).getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase(PROT1)) {

                        device = devicesFactory.get(i);
                        MTConnect mt = new MTConnect(device.getIp(), device.getPort());

                        ParserMTConnect pmtConnect = new ParserMTConnect()
                      pmtConnect.parser(mt.httpCall(), device, logger, ch);

                        //System.out.println();
                    }
                    if (device.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase(PROT2)) {

                    }
                    i++;
                    Thread.sleep(SleepingTime);

                } else {
                    i++;
                }

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            Utility.checkDeviceState(devDAO, device, logger, ch, time);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            Utility.checkDeviceState(devDAO, device, logger, ch, time);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            Utility.checkDeviceState(devDAO, device, logger, ch, time);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            Utility.checkDeviceState(devDAO, device, logger, ch, time);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            Utility.checkDeviceState(devDAO, device, logger, ch, time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            Utility.checkDeviceState(devDAO, device, logger, ch, time);
        } finally {
            if (i < devicesFactory.size()) {
                i++;
            } else if (i == devicesFactory.size()) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class MTConnect extends URLPath {

public MTConnect(String serverIP, String port) {
        super(serverIP, port);

    }


    private byte[] buffer;


    public String getComponetPath() 
    {
        return componentPath="http://"+this.serverIP.toLowerCase()+":"+this.port+"/current?path="+"//Controller/Components/Path/DataItems/DataItem[@type=\"EXECUTION\" or @type=\"PART_COUNT\"]";
    }


    @Override

    public byte[] httpCall() throws IOException,NumberFormatException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(this.getComponetPath()).build();

        Response response;

                response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            buffer=response.body().bytes();


        return buffer;
    }

}
```

I thought to catch OutOfmemoryError, but I found this on StackOverflow:

> Errors tend to signal the end of your application as you know it. It typically cannot be recovered from and should cause your VM to exit. Catching them should not be done except to possibly log or display and appropriate message before exiting.

I'm trying to find out the reason about this error.

Comment: This should be helpful https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. I found out this tool http://fastthread.io/ .I'm analizing my stack trace and I believe to have understood the problem. It should be on this OkHttp ConnectionPool thread. I would find a way to manage thread pool  on httpcall() method. I thought about fork\join framework. Obviously any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I encountered the same problem as you, and my problem has been solved.
>detials: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189059/okhttp3-unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Comment: The people who wrote OkHttpClient suggest you have just one instance, shared across threads: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/